# Build fails on Jenkins when opening jar with JarInputStream

Tags: java, maven, jar, jenkins

I have a multi-module Maven project that I'm building on a Jenkins CI server. One of the modules has some code that needs to open and scan the jar generated by the other modules.

The code identifies the jar path from the classpath and opens it using `JarInputStream`.

```
  jarFile = new JarInputStream(new FileInputStream(jarPath));
  JarEntry jarEntry = jarFile.getNextJarEntry();
```

This code is called from a unit test. The module that contains this code depends on the other modules, so it is built last.

This code builds successfully in the command-line in two different development systems.
My development boxes run Maven 3.2.1 and the Jenkins build server has Maven 3.0.4.

On Jenkins, the code compiles successfully and other tests run, which indicates the jar is available in the classpath. However, when the test attempts to open the jar I get `FileNotFoundException`

`java.io.FileNotFoundException: /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/project1%20-%20review/project1/target/project1-0.6-SNAPSHOT.jar (No such file or directory)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:146)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:101)`

The file is actually present in the workspace since I can see it in the Jenkins web interface.

Comment: which module gets built first ?

Comment: What is the maven version on your jenkins box vs. your development boxes.

Comment: @JigarJoshi I updated the question, they are dependent on each other.

Comment: @JohnFarrelly 3.2.1 and 3.0.4 (I updated the question)

Comment: can you actually check right after it fails on disk if the file is present

Comment: @WillV What maven command are you using for your builds?  `mvn package`, `mvn site` ?

Comment: @JohnFarrelly `mvn clean package -U`

Comment: @JigarJoshi I noticed there are two spaces in the project path which gets passed to the code, so the path is actually `/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/project1%20-%20review/project1/target/project1-0.6-SNAPSHOT.jar`. Does this matter?

Comment: Yes, use [`URLDecoder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLDecoder.html#decode%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) or simply rename jenkins project name

Comment: @JigarJoshi I used URLDecoder and it worked

Comment: I added it as answer you can mark as accepted for others reference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use URLDecoder to decode URL or simply rename your jenkins project to not have spaces in the name